# Machine Learning Output on Kivy Screen

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning python kivy for some project. I have a machine learning code ( Sentiment analysis on movie reviews) and i want the output to be displayed in a kivy window. I tried various things , but am still struggling ! Can anyone help me out with this ?!!

```
**main.py**
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import nltk
import random
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
import pickle
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Demo(GridLayout):
    data = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()        
        self.data =  self.machine()

    def machine(self):
        documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
                     for category in movie_reviews.categories()
                     for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

        random.shuffle(documents)


        all_words = []
        for w in movie_reviews.words():
            all_words.append(w.lower())

        all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

        word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

        def find_features(document):
            words = set(document)
            features = {}
            for w in word_features:
                features[w] = (w in words)

            return features

        featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, 
category) in documents]

        # Training and testing sets splitted up.
        training_set = featuresets[:1900]
        testing_set = featuresets[1900:]        
        classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

        # Testing now.

        print("Naive Bayes Algorithm accuracy percent:", 
(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set)) * 100)

        # most valuable words when it comes to positive and negative 
movie reviews.
        classifier.show_most_informative_features(15)

        # saving the classifier
        save_classifier = open("naivebayes.pickle", "wb")
        pickle.dump(classifier, save_classifier)
        save_classifier.close()

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Demo()

DemoApp().run()
```

I am not getting what to do to get the output from the machine learning code to the kivy . I tried using boxlayout and grid layout, but i am missing something, that i donot understand !

Demo.kv

```
    <Demo>:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: id_label 
            text: root.data
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do `self.data = self.machine ()` but `machine` method returns `None`. You should return the string you want to be displayed.

However, if your function takes a relatively long time to return your GUI will freeze. In this case you must use another thread or process to execute the function. The simplest thing is to use another thread and `@mainthread` decorator to update the `StringProperty` (Since OpenGL related operations should be done only in the main thread).

Example:

```
import threading
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import mainthread


class Demo(GridLayout):
    data = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        threading.Thread(target=self.machine).start()

    def machine(self):
        time.sleep(5)  # Simulating blocking code.
        result = "Hello StackOverflow"
        self.update_label(result)  # Updating label

    @mainthread
    def update_label(self, string):
        self.data = string


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Demo()


MainApp().run()
```